# I wan sum of all the numerical values ​of that column

Tags: python, csv

I want Write a Python function that takes the path of the CSV file and the name of the column as input and calculates the sum of all the numerical values ​​of that column. I know about pandas, But I want to solve it only from the csv module.

```
import csv


def sum(file, column):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in data:
            print(sum(line[column]))


column = 'salary'
file = 'test.csv'
sum(file, column)
```

Comment: You know how to read a csv file line by line. You can get the value in the column. So just make a variable with a value of 0 before your loop and in each iteration of the loop add to that value (you may have to convert a string to a number here). Return the variable from your function.

Comment: You may not believe that with the help you gave me, when I performed, I just shouted and your suggestion was completely correct   count = 0
        for line in data:
            count += int(line[column])
        return count

Comment: You can use a generator: `print(sum(int(line[column]) for line in data))`

Comment: Don't write a function called *sum*. That's the name of a built-in function. Your code will generate a TypeError exception if the CSV file exists and has a column called *salary*

Comment: @comiser, congrats on figuring this out through the comments! :) Please consider posting your own answer to this question and accepting it “to close the loop”; or just delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sum()* is a built-in function. You should not "shadow" a built-in by writing a function of the same name **unless** there's a very good reason. In this case the function signature is completely different to the standard *sum()* function and so is not a reasonable override.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
import csv

def sum_column(file: str, column: str) -> float:
    with open(file) as f:
        data = csv.DictReader(f)
        return sum(float(row[column]) for row in data)

column = 'salary'
file = 'test.csv'
print(sum_column(file, column))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv


def sum(file, column):
     with open(file) as f:
         data = csv.DictReader(f)

         count = 0
         for line in data:
             count += int(line[column])
         return count


column = 'salary'
file = 'test.csv'
print(sum(file, column))
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should not "shadow" the builtin function *sum()*. Why are you converting the values to *int*?

Comment: Because it gave an error and it was corrected, of course, your solution is short